# How to automate the orientation process for a 3D Model such that it has maximum alignment with Global Z axis?

Tags: scripting, physics, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody, 3d-cursor

I have a scan of a banana-like object. For the time being, let's assume I'm importing the STL file of a 3D-scanned Banana, which is bulbous on one side (is heavier on that side).

It gets imported into the scene at a random orientation, and I do the following steps to make it easier to work with:

1. Object > Set Origin to Center of Mass (Volume)
2. Object > Snap > Selection to Cursor

This brings the banana to the default 3D Cursor at Grid Origin. Now, before I can carry on with further steps, I need to align it vertically (as much as possible), which is achieved manually by rotating the object about its Center of Mass (coincident with origin) around the X-axis.

**How can I automate this process?**

I want the banana to be aligned so that the heavier part is below the XY plane, the lighter part is above the XY plane, and the entire model is as vertically aligned as possible.

It can be understood as: the vertical axis of the object should be more or less inclined perfectly with the global Z axis.

Comment: i am sorry, but i have no idea how you want that to be aligned. Maybe a sketch would make it clearer?

Comment: I assume you are wanting to automate this because there would be several more objects similar to this that you'd want to import? Or are you struggling with learning how to rotate/move models? Photogrammetry (scanned) models can often have millions of polygons so it would be difficult to automate what you are describing. There are snapping tools that can help move/rotate an object to line up with a polygon of another object but it is using the origin (including the orientation) of the moved object to do this. So I don't think it would be helpful with what you described.

Comment: @Chris I think what they're asking for is an **Oriented, Minimum-Volume Bounding Box** (which you would then align to the world Z on its longer axis): https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bounding_box I think this is an interesting question, just worded poorly. There is an example done in *Grasshopper* (*Rhino*'s procedural system) here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SOQE1WHuTHc But I think we need loops for it to work since it's an iterative algorithm, as far as I can see.

Comment: Hey! Actually, there will only be one such object in the scene - the automation process is because we're doing some changes to the Bananathing's geometry through scripts, and we also need this little kink to be ironed out since the script only works when Bananthing is oriented vertically. 

I get what you're saying in the second paragraph. I will try to look for any methods involving snapping. Pehaps Bananathing could be snapped *normally* to a tall box.

Comment: @Chris, you're right. I'll add try adding gifs to explain the question better
 I am not entirely sure if this is a Bounding Box problem; give me some time to figure this out. Thanks for sharing this!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a script like this to find the furthest vertex (from the center of mass) and make it the highest vertex:

```py
import bpy
from bpy import context as C

bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_CENTER_OF_VOLUME', center='MEDIAN')
C.object.location = 0, 0, 0
furthest_vert = max(C.object.data.vertices, key=lambda v:v.co.length)
mat = furthest_vert.co.to_track_quat('Z', 'Y').to_matrix().to_4x4().inverted()
C.object.data.transform(mat)
```

[image]

Banana taken from here: https://free3d.com/3d-model/banana-v01--276226.html

Comment: Wow, this is amazing!! Before I try this out, could you explain what is happening in the mat line? I'm sorry to make you do this but I'm new to scripting, and would appreciate your response.

Comment: @DebapriyaKar it takes the coordinate of the `furthest_vert`, and calculates a quaternion rotation required to move $(0, 0, 1)$ coordinate to that point. Then it converts this quateternion to a 4x4 matrix, and inverts it (because you want to undo that rotation).